# Find the indices of an element in a nested list?

Tags: r, list, recursion, nested

I have a list like:

```
mylist <- list(a = 1, b = list(A = 1, B = 2), c = list(C = 1, D = 3))
```

is there an (loop-free) way to identify the positions of the elements, e.g. if I want to replace a values of "C" with 5, and it does not matter where the element "C" is found, can I do something like:

```
Aindex <- find_index("A", mylist)
mylist[Aindex] <- 5
```

I have tried `grepl`, and in the current example, the following will work:

```
mylist[grepl("C", mylist)][[1]][["C"]]
```

but this requires an assumption of the nesting level.

The reason that I ask is that I have a deep list of parameter values, and a named vector of replacement values, and I want to do something like

```
 replacements <- c(a = 1, C = 5)
 for(i in names(replacements)){ 
    indx <- find_index(i, mylist)
    mylist[indx] <-  replacements[i]
  }
```

this is an adaptation to my previous question, [update a node (of unknown depth) using xpath in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13851890/513006), using R lists instead of XML

Answer (score 8):

One method is to use `unlist` and `relist`.

```
mylist <- list(a = 1, b = list(A = 1, B = 2), c = list(C = 1, D = 3))
tmp <- as.relistable(mylist)
tmp <- unlist(tmp)
tmp[grep("(^|.)C$",names(tmp))] <- 5
tmp <- relist(tmp)
```

Because list names from unlist are concatenated with a `.`, you'll need to be careful with `grep` and how your parameters are named. If there is not a `.` in any of your list names, this should be fine. Otherwise, names like `list(.C = 1)` will fall into the pattern and be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26154252/easily-finding-and-replacing-every-match-in-a-nested-list), you could try it recursively like this:

```
find_and_replace <- function(x, find, replace){
  if(is.list(x)){
    n <- names(x) == find
    x[n] <- replace
    lapply(x, find_and_replace, find=find, replace=replace)
  }else{
    x
  }
}
```

Testing in a deeper `mylist`:

```
mylist <- list(a = 1, b = list(A = 1, B = 2), c = list(C = 1, D = 3, d = list(C=10, D=55)))
find_and_replace(mylist, "C", 5)
$a
[1] 1

$b
$b$A
[1] 1

$b$B
[1] 2


$c
$c$C  ### it worked
[1] 5

$c$D
[1] 3

$c$d
$c$d$C ### it worked
[1] 5

$c$d$D
[1] 55
```

Answer (score 0):

This can now also be done using `rrapply` in the `rrapply`-package (an extended version of base `rapply`). To return the position of an element in the nested list based on its name, we can use the special arguments `.xpos` and `.xname`. For instance, to look up the position of the element with name `"C"`:

```r
library(rrapply)

mylist <- list(a = 1, b = list(A = 1, B = 2), c = list(C = 1, D = 3))

## get position C-node
(Cindex <- rrapply(mylist, condition = function(x, .xname) .xname == "C", f = function(x, .xpos) .xpos, how = "unlist"))
#> c.C1 c.C2 
#>    3    1
```

We could then update its value in the nested list with:

```
## update value C-node
mylist[[Cindex]] <- 5
```

The two steps can also be combined directly in the call to `rrapply`:

```r
rrapply(mylist, condition = function(x, .xname) .xname == "C", f = function(x) 5, how = "replace")
#> $a
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $b
#> $b$A
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $b$B
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> 
#> $c
#> $c$C
#> [1] 5
#> 
#> $c$D
#> [1] 3
```