# Get element names in rapply

Tags: r

The little-used `rapply` function should be a perfect solution to many problems (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14655735/find-the-indices-of-an-element-in-a-nested-list/14655813#14655735) ).  However, it leaves the user-written function `f` with no ability to know where it is in the tree.

Is there any way to pass the name of the element in the nested list to `f` in an `rapply` call?  Unfortunately, `rapply` calls `.Internal` pretty quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with nested lists with arbitrary depth recently. Eventually, I came up to more or less acceptable decision in my case. It is not the direct answer to your question (no `rapply` usage), but it seems to be solving the same kind of problems. I hope it can be of some help.

Instead of trying to access names of list elements inside `rapply` I generated vector of names and queried it for elements.

```
# Sample list with depth of 3
mylist <- list(a=-1, b=list(A=1,B=2), c=list(C=3,D=4, E=list(F=5,G=6)))
```

Generating of names vector is a tricky in my case. Specifically, names of list elements should be safe, i.e. without `.` symbol.

```
list.names <- strsplit(names(unlist(mylist)), split=".", fixed=TRUE)
node.names <- sapply(list.names, function(x) paste(x, collapse="$"))
node.names <- paste("mylist", node.names, sep="$")
node.names

[1] "mylist$a"     "mylist$b$A"   "mylist$b$B"   "mylist$c$C"   "mylist$c$D"   "mylist$c$E$F"
[7] "mylist$c$E$G"
```

Next step is accessing list element by string name. I found nothing better than using temporary file.

```
f <- function(x){
  fname <- tempfile()
  cat(x, file=fname)
  source(fname)$value
}
```

Here `f` just returns value of `x`, where `x` is a string with full name of list element.

Finally, we can query list in *pseudo-recursive* way.

```
sapply(node.names, f)
```

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the question [Find the indices of an element in a nested list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14655735/find-the-indices-of-an-element-in-a-nested-list/14655813), you can write:

```
rappply <- function(x, f) {
  setNames(lapply(seq_along(x), function(i) {
    if (!is.list(x[[i]])) f(x[[i]], .name = names(x)[i])
    else rappply(x[[i]], f)
  }), names(x)) 
}
```

then,

```
> mylist <- list(a = 1, b = list(A = 1, B = 2), c = list(C = 1, D = 3))
> 
> rappply(mylist, function(x, ..., .name) {
+   switch(.name, "a" = 1, "C" = 5, x)
+ })
$a
[1] 1

$b
$b$A
[1] 1

$b$B
[1] 2


$c
$c$C
[1] 5

$c$D
[1] 3
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update June 2020**: the `rrapply`-function in the `rrapply`-package (an extended version of base `rapply`) allows to do this by defining the argument `.xname` in the `f` function. Inside `f`, the `.xname` variable will evaluate to the name of the element in the nested list:

```
library(rrapply)

L <- list(a = 1, b = list(A = 1, B = 2), c = list(C = 1, D = 3))

rrapply(L, f = function(x, .xname) paste(.xname, x, sep = " = "))
#> $a
#> [1] "a = 1"
#> 
#> $b
#> $b$A
#> [1] "A = 1"
#> 
#> $b$B
#> [1] "B = 2"
#> 
#> 
#> $c
#> $c$C
#> [1] "C = 1"
#> 
#> $c$D
#> [1] "D = 3"
```